# Тригер на изменение текста в input

Tags: jquery, триггер

Какое событие нужно использовать, чтобы оно срабатывало каждый раз, когда в input добавляется новый символ? `.on('change')` срабатывает только тогда, когда текст уже введён и с input был убран фокус, а потому не подходит.

Comment: on('input' function () {})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно [`oninput`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp), [`onkeypress`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp), [`onkeyup`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) или [`onkeydown`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp).

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  console.log('INPUT: '+this.value);
});

$('input').on('keypress', function() {
  console.log('KEYPRESS: '+this.value);
});

$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  console.log('KEYUP: '+this.value);
});

$('input').on('keydown', function() {
  console.log('KEYDOWN: '+this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
```